# Whats the best way to get content from WordPress into an Android app?

Tags: android, json, wordpress, rss

I have a wordpress website that I want to create into a native app for Android. What are my options for getting content from the site?

I have looked into XML Parsing of the RSS feeds, and JSON API/JSON Feed. The api for JSON said it is outdated and possibly not working on new versions of wordpress websites.

What is my best options?

I need to get the post Title, Image, and Text.

Comment: I believe RSS would be the simplest , but if you want something more native , have a look  @david.binda suggestion to take some functions from the opensource project ..

Comment: As of mid-2015, The JSON API has quite a lot of features, so I would use that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can benefit from WordPress for Android project source codes: http://android.wordpress.org/development/